# Modifying existing xml-file

Tags: python, xml

I need to modify an existing xml file. The actual file looks like this:

```
<person id="1">
    <address>Fr.</address>
    <titles/>
    <firstname>Mary</firstname>
    <lastname>Müller</lastname>
    <gender>F</gender>
    <profession/>
    <references>
        <reference>
            <positions>
                <position>68-590-1</position>
                <position>68-590-2</position>
            </positions>
            <positions>
                <position>68-590-6</position>
                <position>68-590-7</position>
            </positions>
        </reference>
    </references>
</person>
```

My question is: How can I read in such files and then add information. For example, if the person has the profession "professor", (which is written at position 12-122-3), the modified xml should look like this:

```
<person id="1">
    <address>Fr.</address>
    <titles/>
    <firstname>Mary</firstname>
    <lastname>Müller</lastname>
    <gender>F</gender>
    <profession>professor</profession>
    <references>
        <reference>
            <positions>
                <position>12-122-3</position>
            </positions>
            <positions>
                <position>68-590-1</position>
                <position>68-590-2</position>
            </positions>
            <positions>
                <position>68-590-6</position>
                <position>68-590-7</position>
            </positions>
        </reference>
    </references>
</person>
```

Thanks for any help! :)

What I've done so far:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse('SAC-Jahrbuch_1895_mul-ner.xml')
person = doc.getElementsByTagName('person')
lastnames = doc.getElementsByTagName('lastname')
positions = doc.getElementsByTagName('position')
professions = doc.getElementsByTagName('profession')
for ln in lastnames:
        for pos in positions:
                if ln.firstChild.nodeValue == u"Müller" and pos.firstChild.nodeValue == "68-590-2":
                    print "right person"
```

Now, how can I check if the person has already a profession? If not: How can I add the profession AND the position? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you done so far? Did you try to follow at least one XML in Python tutorials?

Comment: I tried it with minidom. But it didn't work. I'll try again...

Comment: In the long run you will probably want to work with [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/). You can follow a tutorial [here](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html).

Comment: Ok, I tried it using minidom (see my edits). But if it's possible with lxml, I'd be interested, too ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple to load xml file then you can do anything like modify node value , delete nodes , create nodes 
in your case , let us say you have an existing file "person.xml" and its url is for example
"xmls/person.xml"
write the following code in a php file let's say "person.php"

```
//so let us begin with loading "person.xml"   
 $root = simplexml_load_file("xmls/person.xml");
 $person = $root->xpath("/person[profession='professor']");
 for($i = 0; $i < count($person); $i++) 
 {
   //i will modify just the first position and you can do this for the other
   $person[$i]->references->reference->positions[0]->position[0]="12-122-3";
 }

 $root->asXml("xmls/person.xml");
```

and you can modify any position you want

Comment: i am really sorry , i have no idea about doing this in python